# getting and setting mac file and folder finder labels from Python

Tags: python, macos, finder

I have been trying to find out how to get and set the colour of file labels from python.

The closest thing I've found to a solution was [this](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythonmac-sig/2005-August/014944.html), but I can't seem to find the module macfile anywhere. Am I just not looking hard enough?

Is there a different way to achieve this if not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this in python using the [xattr](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xattr) module.

Here is an example, taken mostly from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/295151/mac-os-x-is-there-a-straightforward-way-to-color-ls-output-according-to-finder):

```
from xattr import xattr

colornames = {
    0: 'none',
    1: 'gray',
    2: 'green',
    3: 'purple',
    4: 'blue',
    5: 'yellow',
    6: 'red',
    7: 'orange',
}

attrs = xattr('./test.cpp')

try:
    finder_attrs = attrs['com.apple.FinderInfo']
    color = finder_attrs[9] >> 1 & 7
except KeyError:
    color = 0

print colornames[color]
```

Since I have colored this file with the red label, this prints `'red'` for me. You can use the xattr module to also write a new label back to disk.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to set the colour this way too? edit: hm just had a play and this doesn't work for folders. might need to find something else

Comment: This only gets the last color set (in Mavericks), do you know if it's possible to get all the colors, as well as the associated tag names ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have mavericks

Comment: This does not support files with multiple tags assigned.

Answer (score 5):

If you follow favoretti's link and then scroll down a bit, there's a link to
https://github.com/danthedeckie/display_colors, which does this via `xattr`, but without the binary manipulations. I rewrote his code a bit:

```
from xattr import xattr

def set_label(filename, color_name):
    colors = ['none', 'gray', 'green', 'purple', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'orange']
    key = u'com.apple.FinderInfo'
    attrs = xattr(filename)
    current = attrs.copy().get(key, chr(0)*32)
    changed = current[:9] + chr(colors.index(color_name)*2) + current[10:]
    attrs.set(key, changed)

set_label('/Users/chbrown/Desktop', 'green')
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this question is still relevant to anybody but there is a new package "mac-tag" that solves this issue.

```
pip install mac-tag
```

and then you have functions like:

```
function    __doc__
mac_tag.add(tags, path) # add tags to path(s)
mac_tag.find(tags, path=None)   # return a list of all paths with tags, limited to path(s) if present
mac_tag.get(path)   # return dict where keys are paths, values are lists of tags. equivalent of tag -l
mac_tag.match(tags, path)   # return a list of paths with with matching tags
mac_tag.parse_list_output(out)  # parse tag -l output and return dict
mac_tag.remove(tags, path)  # remove tags from path(s)
mac_tag.update(tags, path)  # set path(s) tags. equivalent of `tag -s
```

complete documentation at: https://pypi.org/project/mac-tag/

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

The `macfile` module is part of the [`appscript`](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/) module, and was renamed to `mactypes` in ["2006-11-20 -- 0.2.0"](https://github.com/mattneub/appscript/blob/master/rb-appscript/tags/rb-appscript-0.2.1/CHANGES#L18)

Using this module, here are two functions to get and set the finder labels with appscript version 1.0:

```
from appscript import app
from mactypes import File as MacFile


# Note these label names could be changed in the Finder preferences,
# but the colours are fixed
FINDER_LABEL_NAMES = {
    0: 'none',
    1: 'orange',
    2: 'red',
    3: 'yellow',
    4: 'blue',
    5: 'purple',
    6: 'green',
    7: 'gray',
}


def finder_label(path):
    """Get the Finder label colour for the given path

    >>> finder_label("/tmp/example.txt")
    'green'
    """
    idx = app('Finder').items[MacFile(path)].label_index.get()
    return FINDER_LABEL_NAMES[idx]


def set_finder_label(path, label):
    """Set the Finder label by colour

    >>> set_finder_label("/tmp/example.txt", "blue")
    """

    label_rev = {v:k for k, v in FINDER_LABEL_NAMES.items()}

    available = label_rev.keys()
    if label not in available:
        raise ValueError(
            "%r not in available labels of %s" % (
                label,
                ", ".join(available)))

    app('Finder').items[MacFile(path)].label_index.set(label_rev[label])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Touch file
    path = "blah"
    open(path, "w").close()

    # Toggle label colour
    if finder_label(path) == "green":
        set_finder_label(path, "red")
    else:
        set_finder_label(path, "green")
```

Comment: At least in OSX 10.9.5, files don’t seem to have a "label_index" any more. I used similar code for years, but reviving an old project it doesn’t work any more, while the other approach does.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this folder:

[image]

Notice that some files have multiple tags. One tag is `Work` which is a custom tag.

There are three ways that I have used to get the Finder tags into Python.

---

First, use `xattr` to generate a binary `plist` of extended attributes from the key `'com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags'` and then convert that to a list with [plistlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/plistlib.html):

```
import xattr
import plistlib 

def get_tags_xattr(fn):
    try:
        bpl=xattr.getxattr(fn, 'com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags')
        rtr=[e.partition('\n')[0] 
                  for e in plistlib.loads(bpl, fmt=plistlib.FMT_BINARY)]
        return rtr if rtr else None
    
    except OSError:
        return None
```

---

The second is to use the program [tag](https://github.com/jdberry/tag/) which can be installed with `brew`:

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE

def get_tags_tag(fn):
    if 'com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags' in xattr.listxattr(fn):
        rtr=run(['tag', '-g', '--no-name', fn], 
            stdout=PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8').splitlines()
        return rtr if rtr else None
    
    return None
```

---

The third is to use the PyPi module [osxmetadata](https://pypi.org/project/osxmetadata/):

```
import osxmetadata

def get_tags_osxmeta(fn):
    tags=[t.name for t in osxmetadata.OSXMetaData(fn).tags]
    if tags:
        return tags 
    
    return None
```

Here is a demo of all three:

```
from pathlib import Path 

p=Path('/tmp/test')

for fn in (fn for fn in p.glob('*') if fn.is_file()):
    print(fn, get_tags_osxmeta(fn), 
          get_tags_tag(fn), 
          get_tags_xattr(fn))
```

Prints on that sample folder:

```
/tmp/test/DSC_2930-m.jpg ['Red', 'Green'] ['Green', 'Red'] ['Red', 'Green']
/tmp/test/DSC_2929.JPG None None None
/tmp/test/DSC_2939.JPG None None None
/tmp/test/DSC_2938.JPG ['Red'] ['Red'] ['Red']
/tmp/test/DSC_2937.JPG None None None
/tmp/test/DSC_2942-m.jpg ['Red', 'Orange', 'Gray', 'Work'] ['Gray', 'Orange', 'Red', 'Work'] ['Red', 'Orange', 'Gray', 'Work']
/tmp/test/DSC_2934.JPG ['Red'] ['Red'] ['Red']
/tmp/test/DSC_2930.JPG None None None
/tmp/test/DSC_2931.JPG None None None
/tmp/test/DSC_2933.JPG None None None
/tmp/test/DSC_2932.JPG ['Red'] ['Red'] ['Red']
/tmp/test/DSC_2941.JPG None None None
/tmp/test/DSC_2942.JPG None None None
```

The *best* of those (that which I use most often) is the [osxmetadata](https://pypi.org/project/osxmetadata/) module. It is fast and very flexible. If you just need the tags, the other ways work well too. The first is likely the fastest.